# How can I find in which line was the error throw during seeding Laravel database?

Tags: laravel, seed, seeding, laravel-seeding

I have an error thrown in console during database seeding:

```
"Trying to get property of non-object"
```

But I can't find the line because there are to much files. Is there any hint on how to cope with such a situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using artisan there is a `-v` flag that stands for verbose.

And if you need more messages there are also `-vv -vvv`.

Also you can run your seeder classes separately to debug this issue.

`php artisan db:seed --class=PostSeeder`

Comment: tnx mate, I did not even know about such an option